# How to remove a folder created by old version of application with files during upgrade in advanced installer

Tags: upgrade, directory, advanced-installer

Many thanks in advance, I am using advanced installer 12.1, the scenario is we have already installed application with some custom location feature and is extends the default application location, this installation creates some folders to store temporary files like "Temporary" folder, this folder is used by the application on every minute basis and hence there are some files in this folder, now issue is when i run a new build or try to install the new version of the application, i again select the another custom location, before finishing the installation the installer deleting all the folders installed with older version but not deleting the folders which contains files created by the application e.g the temporary directory above is deleted if it is empty but when it is non-empty it is not removed.

Solution i tried:
1) I used file Removal tool to remove the file, but i think it point the current location and not pointing the older application path.
2) A custom VB script, but again the same issue as #1
3) I tried uninstall cleanup wizard, result #1

Please guide me how i can delete that folder, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The uninstall cleanup wizard should help you get the job done. If you could not get it work correctly write to our support team, at support at advancedinstaller dot com. Also include the .aip file as attachment and our team will try to help you ASAP.